# Group DatetimeIndex by day with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have indexed my dataframe to a DateTimeIndex like so:

```
timstamp                 _id
2018-05-09 16:56:40.940  somedata1
2018-05-09 16:54:03.959  somedata2
2018-05-10 16:53:42.975  somedata3
2018-05-11 16:52:44.897  somedata4
2018-05-11 16:46:35.902  somedata5
```

And I would like to show the frequency of each of the dates like so:

```
day                      count
2018-05-09               2
2018-05-10               1
2018-05-11               2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df.groupby(df.timestampe.dt.date).size()` or `df.timestampe.dt.date.value_counts()`

Comment: Please clarify whether you meant "by date" rather than "by day" (day-of-week: Monday, Tuesday, or 0..6), as you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `str.split` + `groupby` + `count`

```
df.groupby(df['timstamp'].str.split().str[0])._id.count().reset_index()

     timstamp  _id
0  2018-05-09    2
1  2018-05-10    1
2  2018-05-11    2
```

---

## `to_datetime` + `groupby` + `count`

```
df.assign(
    timstamp=pd.to_datetime(df['timstamp']).dt.floor('D')
).groupby('timstamp', as_index=False)._id.count()
```

Or,

```
df['timstamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timstamp']).dt.floor('D')
df.groupby('timstamp', as_index=False)._id.count()
```

```
    timstamp  _id
0 2018-05-09    2
1 2018-05-10    1
2 2018-05-11    2
```

Comment: cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Please edit the question if it meant to say "by day" (day-of-week: Monday, Tuesday, or 0..6) rather than "by date". It currently just looks like a duplicate of many others on pandas groupby datetime.

Comment: @smci nope... this is a bonafide dupe and I'm not pleased at all to admit I answered it so readily instead of looking to close :(

Comment: Err, but you can close-as-dupe now... that's what I do when I find out later it's a dupe...

Comment: [datetimeindex].dt.floor('D') is not valid anymore in pandas 1.0. You should prefer [datetimeindex].dayofyear

Answer (score 1):

This is one way.

```
# convert to datetime
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# normalize, count values, convert to dataframe
res = df['timestamp'].dt.normalize()\
                     .value_counts()\
                     .to_frame().reset_index()

# rename columns
res.columns = ['timestamp', 'count']
```

Result:

```
print(res)

   timestamp  count
0 2018-05-09      2
1 2018-05-11      2
2 2018-05-10      1
```